# iOS define String dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

For localization, I can define %@ in localized string and it will be populated dynamically.

But can I do same thing for this one? If I can't, is there any alternative way? I don't want to write function and  call from there.

```
#define MESSAGE @"Event - %@ is now saved in your calender."
```

Comment: Do you look for `stringWithFormat:`? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are not dynamic. That means, that the compiler will write `@"Event - %@ is now saved in your calender."` everywhere you use `MESSAGE`.

But you can replace the `%@` placeholder on runtime using [`stringWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html):

```
#define MESSAGE @"Event - %@ is now saved in your calender."
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:MESSAGE, @"EventName"];
```

`string` will now be: Event - EventName is now saved in your calender.

Comment: I am looking for this one. Thanks you :)